# How can I join two queries on a common relationship in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, join, sqlalchemy, relationship

Suppose I have two classes `ChildA` and `ChildB` which both have a relationship to `Parent`.
Suppose also that I already have two queries defined, `qa` and `qb`, which query the respective child classes.
I want to join `qb` onto `qa` upon having the same `parent`.

If `parent` were just an ordinary column, I could do the following:

```
subquery = qb.subquery()
joined_query = qa.join(subquery, AliasedChildA.parent==subquery.columns.parent)
```

Here, `AliasedChildA` is an alias of `ChildA`. (I have full control over how the queries are being created, but not over the filters that are being applied to them later.)
But now, since `parent` is a relationship, it is not contained in `subquery.columns`.

How can I join `qa` and `qb` upon having the same `parent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below:

```
qa = session.query(ChildA)
qb = session.query(ChildB)
# @note: *qa* and *qb* may include other filters etc, 
# but assuming they do not contain joins on *Parent*
subquery = qb.subquery()
qry = qa.join(Parent).join(subquery)
```

Comment: That's a nice idea. The only problem I have is that I don't know in advance which class `Parent` the relationship `parent` is being mapped on. Maybe I should look into how to gather that information by introspection. (Maybe I should try to solve easier/more natural problems...)

Comment: As long as each `ChildA/B` has only one relationship to `Parent`, it should work. Otherwise, you should know which relationship you require for the purpose of your requirement: `..upon having the same parent`

Answer (score 1):

Try it with `AliasedChildA.parent_id == subquery.c.parent_id` (`and_` a few clauses if you have a composite pk).

Comment: That's the workaround I'm currently trying. However, this relies on the relationship being built upon `parent_id`, and usually I can't control the names of the columns, only of the relationships. Can I somehow find out which column is used to establish the relationship?

Comment: Also, at the end I would like to perform a `join` upon something like `parent1.children == parent2.children`, and I have no idea about how to do that.

Comment: You can do some introspection from orm classes (class.attribute.property.column), but you can't do it from your starting point of a subquery. Play around with an embedded IPython to see what you can introspect.

Comment: You can pass SQLAlchemy fields as arguments to your function directly.

my_join_function(Model1.xxx, Model2.yyy)

You can pass strings and use getattr(model, field_name) as well. I wouldn't recommend wildly introspecting things to find field names that match up. That seems like code smell.

Answer (score 1):

```
query_a.subquery().join(query_b.subquery(), $on_condition...)
```

works for me :)

Comment: What's the format of `$on_condition`? Can you give an example, please?

Comment: @egor83 I forget it after so long time, sorry.